# sql deleting multiple rows of different columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on a way to delete multiple rows of a single SQL database, targeting two columns. ColumnA will always be the same value, and ColumnB will be different values.

I am trying to figure out the correct syntax for something like this:

```
DELETE FROM tableName WHERE (
    ColumnA = 123 AND ColumnB = 1,
    ColumnA = 123 AND ColumnB = 2,
    ColumnA = 123 AND ColumnB = 3,
    ColumnA = 123 AND ColumnB = 4,
    ColumnA = 123 AND ColumnB = 8
);
```

What will be the correct SQL syntax for the above logic?

Comment: Just replace the commas with `OR`s.

Comment: Oh yeah, you even may not need to add parentheses as `AND`s are interpreted before `OR`s already: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/operator-precedence.html

Comment: Try this,  DELETE FROM tableName WHERE (
    ColumnA = 123 AND ColumnB in ( 1, 2,3,4,8);

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will do it:

```
DELETE FROM tableName 
WHERE ColumnA = 123 AND ColumnB IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 8)
```

Answer (score 8):

Replace `,`  with `OR` :

```
where (ColumnA = 123 and ColumnB = 1) or
      (ColumnA = 123 and ColumnB = 2) or
        . . .
      (ColumnA = 123 and ColumnB = 8);
```

This can be also simplified  as :

```
where ColumnA = 123 and
      ColumnB in (1, 2, 3, 4, 8);
```

Answer (score 7):

The simplest solution (as suggested by GMB) is to replace the commas with `OR`.  However, MySQL also supports tuples, so you can use:

```
WHERE (ColumnA, ColumnB) IN ( (123, 1), (123, 2), (123, 3), (123, 4), (123, 8) )
```

Or, if the `ColumnA` values really are all the same, then:

```
WHERE ColumnA = 123 AND
      ColumnB IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 8)
```